# Wrong DATE mapping inside a @Embeddable

Tags: java, mysql, date, jpa, eclipselink

I have a problem, that a `Date`-Type from an `@Embeddable`-Class will not mapped as a `Date`-Type in the MySQL-Database. Instead it gets mapped as `VARCHAR(255)`. With normal `@Entity`-Classes it is working properly.

I am using JPA 2.1 with EclipseLink 2.5.

I have an `@Embeddable`-Class like this:

```
@Embeddable
public class AbsencePeriod implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "\"START\"")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date start;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "\"END\"")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date end;

    public AbsencePeriod() {
    }

}
```

I include it at another class like this:

```
@Entity
public Person extends BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(
            name = "_PERSON_ABSENCEPERIODS",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID")
    )
    @Getter
    @Setter
    private List<AbsencePeriod> absencePeriods;

}
```

I have also a workaround for this, but I want to know, why the wrong mapping happens. Workaround looks like setting the `@ColumnDefinition` manual:

```
@Embeddable
public class AbsencePeriod implements Serializable {

    @Getter
    @Setter
    @Column(name = "\"START\"")
    @Basic
    @Column(columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date start;


}
```

Comment: If you remove the column definition quotes, does it work?  If so, it looks like a bug with the annotation processing when building columns for DDL.

Comment: I am using the `columnDefinition` only in my workaround. It is not working without this, but it should, like it does in the `@Entity`-Class. So my first code snippet shows like it should work with JPA, but it maps the Dates as VARCHARS. With my last code snippet I can workaround this.

Comment: Sorry, I meant the column.  Does it work if you let JPA default the column name to "START" instead of using the "\"START\"" field?